# Facebook Graph Api /userid/links returning blank

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API and I can't seem to get the links data of a Facebook Page. I have the "master" user, owner of the Facebook Pages, and an access token with "manage pages","Read Stream" and "Manage notifications" extended permissions.

I'm able to retrieve the page basic information, like Description and about, but can't seem to get the links data. The funny thing is that in another page, same owner, same access token permissions, I'm able to retrieve the links information without a hitch.

FacebookPage1Id?fields=links   (returns nothing)

FacebookPage2Id?fields=links   (returns the whole comments list)

Seems like the Page 1 has different privileges/visibility settings than the page 2, and does not matter how many times i try to equalize those settings, even the whole configuration, the page 1 does not give the links data.

Am I doing something wrong? did i miss something?... any help would be appreciated...

Comment: File a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: What is the page that is failing?

Comment: Seems like a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1390598507903594

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1574875522729095/